# RDFParser read string

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon

I'm trying to read random install.rdf files of firefox addons on github. I can't figure out how to parse a string and read properties.

I explored rdf parser but got no where. This is my failed attempt:

```
var xmlString = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><RDF xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" xmlns:em="http://www.mozilla.org/2004/em-rdf#"><Description about="urn:mozilla:install-manifest"><em:id>PortableTester@jetpack</em:id><em:version>initial</em:version><em:type>2</em:type><em:bootstrap>true</em:bootstrap><em:unpack>false</em:unpack><!--Firefox--><em:targetApplication><Description><em:id>{ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384}</em:id><em:minVersion>7.0</em:minVersion><em:maxVersion>27.0</em:maxVersion></Description></em:targetApplication><!--Front End MetaData--><em:name>PortableTester</em:name><em:description>Test addon that tries to figure out if Firefox is portable or not.</em:description><em:creator>Noitidart</em:creator><em:optionsURL>options url here</em:optionsURL></Description></RDF>';

var rdfParser = Cc['@mozilla.org/rdf/xml-parser;1'].createInstance(Ci.nsIRDFXMLParser);
var ds = Cc['@mozilla.org/rdf/datasource;1?name=in-memory-datasource'].createInstance(Ci.nsIRDFDataSource);

var emptyUri = Services.io.newURI('urn:none', null, null);
rdfParser.parseString(ds, emptyUri, xmlString);
```

Comment: Thank you to all those to get this re-opened and the mod that re-opened this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks that it is [a process more complicated than it should be](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-release/source/toolkit/mozapps/extensions/internal/AddonUpdateChecker.jsm#125). The following code is just a starting point

```js
const PREFIX_NS_EM = "http://www.mozilla.org/2004/em-rdf#";
var xmlString = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><RDF xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" xmlns:em="http://www.mozilla.org/2004/em-rdf#"><Description about="urn:mozilla:install-manifest"><em:id>PortableTester@jetpack</em:id><em:version>initial</em:version><em:type>2</em:type><em:bootstrap>true</em:bootstrap><em:unpack>false</em:unpack><!--Firefox--><em:targetApplication><Description><em:id>{ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384}</em:id><em:minVersion>7.0</em:minVersion><em:maxVersion>27.0</em:maxVersion></Description></em:targetApplication><!--Front End MetaData--><em:name>PortableTester</em:name><em:description>Test addon that tries to figure out if Firefox is portable or not.</em:description><em:creator>Noitidart</em:creator><em:optionsURL>options url here</em:optionsURL></Description></RDF>';
var rdfParser = Cc['@mozilla.org/rdf/xml-parser;1'].createInstance(Ci.nsIRDFXMLParser);
var ds = Cc['@mozilla.org/rdf/datasource;1?name=in-memory-datasource'].createInstance(Ci.nsIRDFDataSource);

var emptyUri = Services.io.newURI('urn:none', null, null);
rdfParser.parseString(ds, emptyUri, xmlString);
var resources = ds.GetAllResources()
while (resources.hasMoreElements()) {
  let resource = resources.getNext().QueryInterface(Ci.nsIRDFResource);
  let arcs = ds.ArcLabelsOut(resource);
  while (arcs.hasMoreElements()) {
    let arc = arcs.getNext().QueryInterface(Ci.nsIRDFResource);
    let prop = arc.ValueUTF8.substring(PREFIX_NS_EM.length)
    let targets = ds.GetTargets(resource, arc, true);
    while (targets.hasMoreElements()) {
      let target = targets.getNext();
      if (target instanceof Ci.nsIRDFResource) {
        console.log(prop, "Resource node, recurse");
      }
      else if (target instanceof Ci.nsIRDFLiteral) {
        console.log(prop, target.Value); //are non ASCII characters encoded?
      }
      else if (target instanceof Ci.nsIRDFInt) {
        console.log(prop, target.Value);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much paa! I'll share what I used below, it works but it was complicated so  I hoping for another reply. And your reply helps a lot!

Comment: I just tested yours out, it works awesomely I like it a lot! 
With your method I can list out all properties, rather then have ot know the property name before hand!

Answer (score 0):

This works for me but is complicated, @paa's answer helps understand stuff, its different from paa's in that you need to know the property name before hand, then you can call to get it's value.

```
//start boilerplate stuff straing ocpied from https://github.com/johan/greasemonkey-old-partial-history/blob/2431aa17187e7a84ed2f7a5f5f757bcc4a34e4d1/src/chrome/chromeFiles/content/updater.js#L198
var RDFURI_INSTALL_MANIFEST_ROOT = 'urn:mozilla:install-manifest';
var PREFIX_NS_EM = 'http://www.mozilla.org/2004/em-rdf#';
var PROP_METADATA = ["id", "version", "type", "internalName", "updateURL", "updateKey", "optionsURL", "optionsType", "aboutURL", "iconURL", "icon64URL"];

var gRDF = Cc['@mozilla.org/rdf/rdf-service;1'].getService(Ci.nsIRDFService)

function EM_R(aProperty) {
    return gRDF.GetResource(PREFIX_NS_EM + aProperty);
}

function getRDFValue(aLiteral) {
    if (aLiteral instanceof Ci.nsIRDFLiteral)
        return aLiteral.Value;
    if (aLiteral instanceof Ci.nsIRDFResource)
        return aLiteral.Value;
    if (aLiteral instanceof Ci.nsIRDFInt)
        return aLiteral.Value;
    return null;
}

function getRDFProperty(aDs, aResource, aProperty) {
        return getRDFValue(aDs.GetTarget(aResource, EM_R(aProperty), true));
}
//end boilerplate stuff straing ocpied from https://github.com/johan/greasemonkey-old-partial-history/blob/2431aa17187e7a84ed2f7a5f5f757bcc4a34e4d1/src/chrome/chromeFiles/content/updater.js#L198

//start - my personal stuff, all the above is just boilerplate
var xmlString = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><RDF xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" xmlns:em="http://www.mozilla.org/2004/em-rdf#"><Description about="urn:mozilla:install-manifest"><em:id>PortableTester@jetpack</em:id><em:version>initial</em:version><em:type>2</em:type><em:bootstrap>true</em:bootstrap><em:unpack>false</em:unpack><!--Firefox--><em:targetApplication><Description><em:id>{ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384}</em:id><em:minVersion>7.0</em:minVersion><em:maxVersion>27.0</em:maxVersion></Description></em:targetApplication><!--Front End MetaData--><em:name>PortableTester</em:name><em:description>Test addon that tries to figure out if Firefox is portable or not.</em:description><em:creator>Noitidart</em:creator><em:optionsURL>options url here</em:optionsURL></Description></RDF>';

var uri = Cc["@mozilla.org/network/io-service;1"].getService(Ci.nsIIOService).newURI('urn:empty', null, null);
var parser = Cc["@mozilla.org/rdf/xml-parser;1"].createInstance(Ci.nsIRDFXMLParser);
var memoryDS = Cc["@mozilla.org/rdf/datasource;1?name=in-memory-datasource"].createInstance(Ci.nsIRDFDataSource);
parser.parseString(memoryDS, uri, xmlString);

var dsResources = memoryDS.GetAllResources();

let root = gRDF.GetResource(RDFURI_INSTALL_MANIFEST_ROOT);

let addon = {};
addon.unpack = getRDFProperty(ds, root, 'unpack');
PROP_METADATA.forEach(function(aProp) {
    addon[aProp] = getRDFProperty(ds, root, aProp);
});
console.log('addon:', addon);
```